# bash recursion automatically ends after single level

Tags: bash

Why is this `make_request` function ending just after a single traversal?

```bash
make_request(){
    path="${1//' '/'%20'}"
    echo $path
    mkdir -p $HOME/"$1"
    $(curl --output $HOME/"$1"/$FILE_NAME -v -X GET $BASE_URL"/"$API_METHOD"/"$path &> /dev/null)
    # sample response from curl
    # {
    #     "count":2,
    #     "items": [
    #         {"path": "somepath1", "type": "folder"},
    #         {"path": "somepath2", "type": "folder"},
    #     ]
    # }
    count=$(jq ".count" $HOME/"$1"/$FILE_NAME)
    for (( c=0; c<$count; c++ ))
    do
        child=$(jq -r ".items[$c] .path" $HOME/"$1"/$FILE_NAME);
        fileType=$(jq -r ".items[$c] .type" $HOME/"$1"/$FILE_NAME);
        if [ "$fileType" == "folder" ]; then
            make_request "$child"
        fi
    done
}

make_request "/"
```

`make_request "/"` should give the following output:

```
/folder
/folder/folder1-1
/folder/folder1-1/folder1-2
/folder/foler2-1
/folder/folder2-1/folder2-2
/folder/folder2-1/folder2-3 ...
```

but I am getting the following:

```
/folder
/folder/folder1-1
/folder/folder1-1/folder1-2
```

Comment: Why do you have the `curl` command inside `$()`? `$()` is used to substitute the output of a command back into the command line. But there's no output because you're redirecting to `/dev/null`.

Comment: @Barmar I am saving the output of curl using --output to some file and reading it afterward as I am also required to save the output.

Comment: Put `set -x` at the beginning of the script so you see a transcript of all the commands as they're executing.

Comment: I can see that you're saving the output to a file. So there's no stdout, what do you expect to be substituted with `$()`?

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, I think `$()` is not required it is working without `$()` also

Comment: You *aren't* saving the output, `$(curl ...)` would capture the output, then `bash` would try to parse and execute it as another command.  The only reason you don't get an error is that you discard `curl`'s output with `>&/dev/null`, and the unquoted expansion produces nothing to parse (as opposed to an empty string which would produce a 'command not found' error).

Comment: @chepner He's saving the output to a file with the `--output` option.

Comment: @Barmar I meant standard output.

Comment: @chepner `--output filename` is equivalent to using `> filename`. That's not the problem.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) finds several problems with the code.

Comment: See [How can I debug a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/4154375).

Comment: @pjh None of the issues it finds seem significant unless there are spaces in the variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using global variables everywhere. Therefore, the inner call changes the loop variables `c` and `count` of the outer call, resulting in bogus.

Minimal example:

```
f() {
  this_is_global=$1
  echo "enter $1: $this_is_global"
  ((RANDOM%2)) && f "$(($1+1))"
  echo "exit $1: $this_is_global"
}
```

Running `f 1` prints something like

```
enter 1: 1
enter 2: 2
enter 3: 3
exit 3: 3
exit 2: 3
exit 1: 3
```

**Solution:** Make the variables local by writing `local count=$(...)` and so on. For your loop, you have to put an additional statement `local c` above the `for`.

Answer (score 1):

As currently written all variables have *global* scope; this means that all function calls are overwriting and referencing the same set of variables, this in turn means that when a child function returns to the parent the parent will find its variables have been overwritten by the child, this in turn leads to the type of behavior seen here.

In this particular case the loop variable `c` leaves the last child process with a value of `c=$count` and all parent loops now see `c=$count` and thus exit; it actually gets a bit more interesting because `count` is also changing with each function call.  The previous comment to add `set -x` (aka enable debug mode) before the first function call should show what's going on with each variable at each function call.

What OP wants to do is insure each function is working with a `local` copy of a variable.  The easiest approach is to add a `local <variable_list>` at the top of the function, making sure to list ***all*** variables that should be treated as 'local', eg:

```
local path count c child fileType
```

Answer (score 0):

change variables to have local scope instead of global.

```bash
...
local count; # <------ VARIABLE MADE LOCAL
count=$(jq ".count" $HOME/"$1"/$FILE_NAME)
local c; # <------ VARIABLE MADE LOCAL
for (( c=0; c<$count; c++ ))
do
    ....
done
...
```